# Check if directory exists and Permissions

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to write a code to create a file in particular directory.

Although I am able to manage the code to check for file existence and also creating the directory if not exists but how to check if I have the permission to create the directory and/or file at specified place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well try creating the directory or the file and if you don't have permission an exception would be thrown which you can catch and do as needed.

```
try
{
 // code to create directory or file
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
  // do something here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to try to write to it.  You'll get an exception if it's not writable by the current user.

That being said, you should be able to check to see if you can write to a folder like so:

```
string directoryName = GetTheDirectory();

PermissionSet permissionSet = new PermissionSet(PermissionState.None);    

FileIOPermission writePermission = new FileIOPermission(FileIOPermissionAccess.Write, directoryName);

permissionSet.AddPermission(writePermission);

if (permissionSet.IsSubsetOf(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.PermissionSet))
{
   // You have write permissions
}
else
{
   // You don't have write permissions
}
```